# Calling web service from HTML page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web-services

I am having a web service and I want to call it from an HTML page. I used this code in my HTML page:

```
function SendMail() {
         var requestdata = {};
     //    requestdata.Name = "Amar Prakash";
       //  var pdata = { "objRequestData": requestdata };

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             data: JSON.stringify(pdata),
             url: "http://localhost:2345/WebService.asmx/Send_Mail",
             contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                 alert("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS");
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 //alert(xhr.responseText);
                 alert("error");
             }
         });
     }
```

my web service code

```
[WebMethod]
public void Send_Mail()
{
    try
    {
        string fromaddr = "frommail@gmail.com";
        string toaddr = "tomil@gmail.com";
        string bodytxt = "Body Message";
        string sub = "Subject Name";
        bodytxt = "Body Text";

        MailMessage mailreq = new MailMessage(fromaddr, toaddr);
        mailreq.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailreq.Subject = sub;
        mailreq.Body = bodytxt;
        SmtpClient smtpreq = new SmtpClient();
        smtpreq.Send(mailreq);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

but this code didn't enter to the web service function code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what's in `WebService.asmx`.

Comment: Please put the code in your question. (Use the "edit" link right under the tags.)

Answer (score 0):

You should mark `public void Send_Mail()` with `ScriptMethod` attribute.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void Send_Mail()
{
    ...
}
```

Also may be you should mark the hole service class with `ScriptService` attribute.

Comment: i have added this line "[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]" and still the same problem not enter to the function breakpoint

Comment: Have you added `ScriptService` too (but at class level not method)?

Comment: now, it enter to my function , but it didn't form its function. i want to know the function to send mail using webservice please

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

`[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` at class level and `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]` at method level..

This attribute will allow you to access your *.asmx* service to be called from Javascript code.

Comment: i have made this also

Comment: This attributes is applicable on your class not on method.

Comment: is there any thing else i should do, is there is any problem in my code

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your code.
I am doing a sample example just to check which method will reslove your issue..

Comment: Hey,
I got the solution
try to have `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` at class level and `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]` at method level.
It'll work.
I have modified my answer too.